# Accessing url having .svc in my ajax call ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I am trying to access a URL in my ajax call which have `.scv` extension .

when i manually type the url in my browser i get data but when i try using the same url in my ajax call it always goes to error function everytime . i dont quite figure it out what actually i'm missing here .

URL looks like this with http://

```
site.com/myService/myservice.svc/Contacts/123/235
```

**My output:** when i give url in browser

```
[{"ContactNo":"","Countrycode":"","ContactType":"","UserName":"my group1"},{"ContactNo":"","Countrycode":"","ContactType":"","UserName":"my group2"},{"ContactNo":"","Countrycode":"","ContactType":"","UserName":"my group3"}]
```

**Ajax call:**

```
 var serviceUrl= site.com/myService/myservice.svc/Contacts/123/235
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: null,
        processData: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                debugger; // never comes here
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText)
                debugger;
            }
        });
```

Any help on this would be great help .

Comment: Did you do F12 and Check any errors in Console?

Comment: yes i done that console looks clean @Sukanya

Comment: Is this a cross domain request?

Comment: Put your url in quotes and add `http://`. Also tell me the error that is coming on ajax request.

Comment: @charlietfl yes it is . @sukanya in error function i get responsetext `""` status=`0` .

Comment: Can't make cross domain request unless api is CORS enabled or jsonp enabled

Comment: @charlietfl true that . i added `dataType:jsonp` & `crossDomain:true` in my ajax call and made a setting which accepts cross-domain requests in wcf .

Comment: well if you can add your comment as answer i'm happy to mark it .